# Loading Data to a gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and I want to save its content to a CSV file. Then when I run the program again it loads the data from the CSV file to the gridview.

I have this code to save to CSV file:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo todel = new FileInfo(@"c:\dd\GB STOCK.csv");
        todel.Delete();

        int cols;
        //open file 
        StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(@"c:\dd\GB STOCK.csv");

        //determine the number of columns and write columns to file 
        cols = dataGridView1.Columns.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < cols ; i++)
        {
            wr.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name.ToString().ToUpper() + ",");
        }
        wr.WriteLine();

        //write rows to excel file
        for (int i = 0; i < (dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                {
                    wr.Write(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value + ",");
                }
                else
                {
                    wr.Write(",");
                }
            }

            wr.WriteLine();
        }
        //close file
        wr.Close();
    }
```

And this code to load from the csv to the gridview:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string rowValue;
        string[] cellValue;
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(@"C:\dd\GB STOCK.csv"))
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\dd\GB STOCK.csv");
            // Reading header

            rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
            cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');

            for (int i = 0; i <= cellValue.Count() - 1; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                column.Name = cellValue[i];
                column.HeaderText = cellValue[i];
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
            }

            // Reading content
            while (streamReader.Peek() != -1)
            {
                rowValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
                cellValue = rowValue.Split(',');
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellValue);
            }
            streamReader.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No File is Selected");
        }
    }
```

now the problem is that whenever I save and load the gridview it adds one extra column (without header) every time.

Could anybody tell me what is the wrong with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you save you are ending the line with a comma. So when the file gets read back in it thinks there is an extra (empty) value on the end. Try:

```
rowValue.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

While Saving the Data grid values to `CSV`, Check the Count of Grid view Column (How much its coming.? and How much column is actually.?) In Your `button1_Click`.

Carefully debug your code.

Have you tried Something like this in your `button1_Click` also:

```
     `cols = dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1;`
```

**Or**

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cols - 1; i++)
    {
        wr.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].Name.ToString().ToUpper() + ",");
    }
```

Comment: yes I tried this but It showed me the last column without header